# Can I build a command line tool for Windows 7 with Visual Studio Community 2017?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2017

I downloaded Visual Studio Community 2017 because I need to build a command line tool to perform some administrative tasks on Windows 7. Is this possible and if so, what project should I select?

When I create a new project I can not choose "Universal Windows" projects, because these are restricted to Windows 10. A project I can create is a `Class Library (.NET standard)`, but I have no way of executing this as it is a library and won't run from a Main() method, nor am I able to add a Unit Test project, because that is only available for Universal Windows.

I installed a load of extra .NET framework versions, the Windows 8 jdk, I searched for project templates online, created a "Blank Solution" from "Other project types", etc

So the question is basically, how do I build anything that runs on Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question again. I set up Visual Studio for "universal Windows platform" development, because it sounded suitable for the simple app that I wanted to build, but the universal Windows platform is all new and aimed at Windows 10. My bad. After I added ".NET desktop development" via the Open Visual Studio Installer I now have my beloved Console Application project.